# AWS Route53 Alias for www subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have setup an alias for my www subdomain in Route53 however if I go to www.example.net it forwards to the endpoint address: http://example.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

But if I go to the root domain example.net it shows example.net in the address bar instead of the endpoint address (which is what I want to happen).

Why does going to www.example.net forward me to the endpoint address?

This is the tutorial I followed:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html

Comment: Can you post the Zone File?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer here is a screenshot of my hosted zone: http://i.imgur.com/VkkDJcw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen if you misconfigured the "redirect all requests to another host" setting on the www.example.net bucket to reference the example.net bucket's website hosting endpoint, rather than simply to putting "example.net" in the box.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ConfiguringBucketWebsite.html

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I have never use the AWS "Alias" feature.

The documentation says:

> Choose Alias Target. Choose your root domain website endpoint from the
>   list (for example, example.com). Do not select the www subdomain
>   endpoint (for example, www.example.com).

So the ALIAS seems all to be correctly set up for `MYDOMAIN.net`, but you also want to set it up for `www.MYDOMAIN.net`. For this you need to follow the other procedure in the doc:

For the `www.MYDOMAIN.net` alias:

> Choose Alias Target. Select your www subdomain website endpoint from
>   the list (for example, www.example.com). Do not select the root domain
>   endpoint (for example, example.com). For Routing Policy, choose
>   Simple. Leave Evaluate Target Health set to No.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Select my www endpoint when creating the www.mydomain.net alias http://i.imgur.com/009b0NK.png

Comment: It looks like you need two buckets, one named "example.com" and one "www.example.com", see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-s3-tasks Is this the case? In particular, see the part "To redirect requests from www.example.com to example.com"

Comment: Thanks David, that was it. I was redirecting to the endpoint instead of the root bucket.